# ASPX Null Character Bug

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an .aspx page that I'm trying to render, but when I go to render characters, I get strange results.

```
<%= default(char) %>
```

Expands to the following in FF and Chrome, but not in IE:

```
�
```

Is there a way to ignore the value if it's the null character? I've tried `default(char).ToString()`, but it seems have the same result. When there's a null character, I just want to ignore it.

Comment: I think we could help better if you show your real code

Comment: This is my real code, try putting exactly that into an .aspx page and viewing it with FF or Chrome.

Comment: I would like to find a transformation that will print `default(char)` as if it were `""`. Doing `default(char).toString()` only resulted in the same odd character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default value for char is \0 or which is the equivalent of null but not actually a System.Null value, so the behaviour is as expected.

If you want to avoid  that test for:

```
<%= mychar != '\0' ? mychar : '' %>
```

It's important to remember to use single quotes for chars.

My worry is that this is a long way around doing this; what are you actually trying to do in your main code ?

Edit: To give a code sample to the fix paraphrased in my comment:

```
<%= myobj.charProp == '\0' ? "''" : myobj.charProp.ToString() %>
```

Comment: I'm trying to print out a `char` property of an object, but ignore the char if it has not been initialized. I'm creating a JavaScript string, so it would be nice if I could print `''` when `obj.Prop == default(char)` and `'n'` when `obj.Prop == 'n'`.

Comment: ah ok, so something like <%= myobj.charProp == '\0' ? "''" : myobj.charProp.ToString() %>; I've added this to my answer above; you need a string on both sides of the tertiary or the compiler moans at you.

Comment: I'm intrigued what sort of object has a char property, is there a special reason or are you trying to save space, or is it from some kind of interop ?

Comment: It was created that way to enforce a strict compatibility with a `CHAR(1)` field in a db table. The author thought it was clever.

Comment: Ahhh - I share your pain! If it helps a bit, Char's in .Net are implicitly compatible with Int; So if you read it in as such, you could simple do <%= myInt != 0 ? (char)myInt : "''" %> Okay, I'm not totally sure if that makes it any clearer but it might help with mucking around with this odd null comparison.

Comment: Although if was created as such; then I guess you mean you can't control the object either; never mind.  Perhaps you can create a partial class and override the char property to one that has this logic inside it so you don't have to do this whole tertiary bomb in the middle of your markup.